# Replace na's with value from another df

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I have two dataframes below, the first df has ~15k records of number of steps taken by time and date, the second df is the average number of steps per interval time.  What I'm trying to do is go through df1 and replace the na values with the avg.steps value from df2, however I've can't seem to figure it out R.  What would be the most efficient way to do this?  And is there a way to do it using dplyr?

df1 looks like this:

```
steps <- c(51, 516, NA, NA, 161, 7)
interval <- c(915, 920, 925, 930, 935, 940)

steps  interval
   51       915
  516       920
   NA       925
   NA       930
  161       935
    7       940
```

df2 looks like this:

```
avg.steps <- c(51, 516, 245, 0, 161, 7)
interval <- c(915, 920, 925, 930, 935, 940)

avg.steps  interval
       51       915
      516       920
      245       925
        0       930
      161       935
        7       940
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it using `data.table v1.9.6`:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.6+, for 'on=' feature
dt1[is.na(steps), steps := dt2[.SD, avg.steps, on="interval"]]
```

The first argument `i = is.na(steps)` allows us to look at just those rows where `dt1$steps` is `NA`. *On those rows*, we *update* `dt1$steps`. This is done by performing a *join as subset*. `.SD` refers to the *subset of data*, i.e., those rows where `dt1$steps` equals `NA`.

For each row where `steps` is `NA`, we find the corresponding matching row in `dt2` while joining *on* "interval" column.

As an example, `is.na(steps)` would return 3rd row in `dt1` as one of the rows. Finding matching row for `.SD$interval = 925`  with `dt2$interval` would return the index "3" (3rd row in `dt2`). The corresponding `avg.steps` value is "245". Thus 3rd row of `dt1` gets updated with `245`.

Hope this helps.

---

If `dt2` has multiple matches for any `dt1$interval` value, you'll have to decide which value to update with. But I'm guessing it is not the case here.

Comment: I tried the above and get the following error: 

`Error in set(i, j = lc, value = newfactor) : 
  .SD is locked. Updating .SD by reference using := or set are reserved for future use. Use := in j directly. Or use copy(.SD) as a (slow) last resort, until shallow() is exported.`  

I've spent some time researching this and learning more about data.tables but can not figure it out

Comment: Fixed in current devel, [#1341](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1341). Use `copy(.SD)` for now.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the entries are corresponding, it's quite straightforward
      `df1$steps[is.na(df1$steps)] <- df2$avg.steps[is.na(df1$steps)]`

EDIT: 
If they're non-corresponding, then here's a dplyr solution:

`library(dplyr)`

```
df1$steps[is.na(steps)] <- (df1 %>% filter(is.na(steps)) %>% 
    group_by(interval) %>% 
    mutate(steps = rep(df2$avg.steps[df2$interval == interval[1]], length(interval)))$steps
```

Comment: They are not corresponding, df2 only has 288 entries as it is just the means of each interval from df1