# replace NA with values from another table based on groupings (not one-by-one lookup table)

Tags: r, dplyr

My objective is to replace values in one table with values from another look-up table. There is one catch: this lookup table isn't one-by-one lookup table as discussed in [Replace na's with value from another df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33072348/replace-nas-with-value-from-another-df) but the lookup will be done based on multiple column groupings. As a result, if multiple entries are returned based on those groupings in the look-up table, all of them would need to be populated in the original table.

I was able to do this task but I need help with two things:

a) my code is really messy. Every time I have to do similar thing, I end up spending enormous amount of time trying to figure out what I have done, and then re-using it. So, I'd appreciate anything that's more clean and simpler.

b) It's very slow. I have multiple `ifelse` statements. When I run this on the actual data with 36M records, it takes a lot of time.

Here's my source with dummy data:

```
dput(DFile)
structure(list(Region_SL = c("G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G2", "G2", 
"G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G4", "G4", "G4", "G4", "G5", "G5"), 
    Country_SV = c("United States", "United States", "United States", 
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "UK", 
    "UK"), Product_BU = c("Laptop", "Laptop", "Laptop", "Laptop", 
    "Laptop", "Laptop", "Laptop", "Laptop", "Laptop", "Laptop", 
    "Laptop", "Laptop", "Laptop", "Laptop", "Power Cord", "Laptop"
    ), Prob_model3 = c(0, 79647405.9878251, 282615405.328728, 
    NA, NA, 363419594.065383, 0, 72870592.8458704, 260045174.088548, 
    369512727.253779, 0, 79906001.2878251, 285128278.558728, 
    405490639.873629, 234, NA), DoS.FY = c(2014, 2013, 2012, 
    NA, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
    2015, 2016, NA), Insured = c("Covered", "Covered", "Covered", 
    NA, NA, "Not Covered", "Not Covered", "Not Covered", "Not Covered", 
    "Not Covered", "Not Covered", "Not Covered", "Not Covered", 
    "Not Covered", "Covered", NA)), .Names = c("Region_SL", "Country_SV", 
"Product_BU", "Prob_model3", "DoS.FY", "Insured"), row.names = c(NA, 
16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here's my grouped look-up table:

```
dput(Master_Joined)
structure(list(Region_SL = c("G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G2", "G3", 
"G4", "G5", "G5", "G5"), Country_SV = c("United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "UK", "UK", "UK"), Product_BU = c("Laptop", 
"Laptop", "Laptop", "Laptop", "Laptop", "Laptop", "Laptop", "Power Cord", 
"Laptop", "Laptop"), DoS.FY = c(2014, 2013, 2012, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2017), Insured = c("Covered", "Covered", 
"Covered", "Uncovered", "Not Covered", "Not Covered", "Not Covered", 
"Covered", "Uncovered", "Covered")), .Names = c("Region_SL", 
"Country_SV", "Product_BU", "DoS.FY", "Insured"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is "grouped" in a sense that all entries are unique.

Finally, here's my code:

```
#Which fields are missing?
Missing<-DFile[is.na(DFile$Prob_model3),]

Column_name<-colnames(DFile)[4]
colnames(DFile)[4]<-"temp_prob"

#Replace Prob_model3
DFile<-DFile %>%
  group_by(Region_SL, Country_SV, Product_BU) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Average_Value = mean(temp_prob,na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Col_name1 = ifelse(is.na(temp_prob),Average_Value,temp_prob)) %>%
  dplyr::select(Region_SL:Product_BU,DoS.FY,Insured,Col_name1)

colnames(DFile)[6]<-Column_name

  Missing$DoS.FY<-NULL

  Missing_FYear<-Missing %>% 
    inner_join(Master_Joined,by = c("Region_SL", "Country_SV", "Product_BU")) %>%
    group_by(Region_SL, Country_SV, Product_BU, DoS.FY, Insured.y) %>%
    dplyr::distinct() %>%
    left_join(Missing)

  Missing_FYear$Prob_model3<-NULL

  DFile <-DFile %>% 
    left_join(Missing_FYear,by = c("Region_SL", "Country_SV", "Product_BU", "Insured")) %>%
    dplyr::rowwise() %>%
    mutate(DoS.FY=ifelse((is.na(`DoS.FY.y`)|is.na(`DoS.FY.x`)),sum(`DoS.FY.y`,`DoS.FY.x`,na.rm=TRUE),`DoS.FY.x`), Insured_Combined = ifelse(is.na(Insured),Insured.y,Insured)) %>%
    dplyr::select(Region_SL:Product_BU,Prob_model3,DoS.FY, Insured_Combined)  

  colnames(DFile)[6]<-"Insured"
  #Check again
  Missing<-DFile[is.na(DFile$Prob_model3),] 

  if (nrow(Missing) > 1)
  { #you have NaNs, replace them with 0
    DFile[is.nan(DFile$Prob_model3),"Prob_model3"] <- 0
   }
  Missing<-DFile[is.na(DFile$Prob_model3),]
```

---

Expected Output: `DFile` as after the running the code above.

I'd sincerely appreciate your help. I have been struggling with this problem for about a week now.

Comment: @Sotos and Jonathan - Thanks for pointing out. `myout` is exactly as after running `DFile` through the code. if you want, I can post `myout` again; I deleted it because I am not sure what's wrong. I generated it by copy-pasting `DFile` after running it through the code.. Not sure whether that caused the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea is to find the `Region_SL` which have `NA`. Once we do we use `plyr`'s `rbind.fill` to rbind to a `new_df`. We then filter out any rows with `NA` (except on last column - col 6). We create a new variable `Prob_model4` which holds the means per group of `Region_SL`. We then use `coalesce` to "merge" the two columns.

```
library(dplyr)
ind <- unique(as.integer(which(is.na(DFile), arr.ind = TRUE)[,1]))
new_df <- plyr::rbind.fill(Master_joined[Master_joined$Region_SL %in% DFile$Region_SL[ind],], DFile)

new_df %>% 
  arrange(Region_SL, Prob_model3) %>% 
  filter(complete.cases(.[-6])) %>% 
  group_by(Region_SL) %>% 
  mutate(Prob_model3 = replace(Prob_model3, is.na(Prob_model3), mean(Prob_model3, na.rm = T))) %>%  
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 21 × 6
#   Region_SL    Country_SV Product_BU DoS.FY     Insured Prob_model3
#       <chr>         <chr>      <chr>  <dbl>       <chr>       <dbl>
#1         G1 United States     Laptop   2014     Covered           0
#2         G1 United States     Laptop   2013     Covered    79647406
#3         G1 United States     Laptop   2012     Covered   282615405
#4         G1 United States     Laptop   2014     Covered   120754270
#5         G1 United States     Laptop   2013     Covered   120754270
#6         G1 United States     Laptop   2012     Covered   120754270
#7         G1 United States     Laptop   2015   Uncovered   120754270
#8         G2 United States     Laptop   2015 Not Covered   363419594
#9         G2 United States     Laptop   2015 Not Covered   363419594
#10        G3 United States     Laptop   2015 Not Covered           0
# ... with 11 more rows
```

Comment: When I run the commands in the question I get frame with 20 rows. Your answer generates one with 21?

Comment: @JonathanvonSchroeder Yes I noticed. If I remove duplicates I get a data frame with 19 rows which is correct given that OP's data frame has 20 rows with 1 duplicated (G2 - row 9). I chose to leave it like that so OP can manipulate as they want

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think about this is to only merge the rows which have missing values in DoS.FY or Insured with the master data:

```
#Replace missing probabilities by grouped average
DFile_new <- DFile %>% group_by(Region_SL,Country_SV,Product_BU) %>% mutate(Prob_model3 = coalesce(Prob_model3,mean(Prob_model3, na.rm = T))) %>% ungroup()
#This leads to one NaN because for
# 16        G5            UK     Laptop          NA     NA        <NA>
#there are no other rows in the same group
DFile_new$Prob_model3[is.nan(DFile_new$Prob_model3)] <- 0

#Split dataset into two parts
#1) The part that has no NA's in DoS.FY and Insured
DFile_new1 <- filter(DFile_new,!is.na(DoS.FY) & !is.na(Insured))
#2) The part has NA's in either DoS.FY or Insured
DFile_new2 <- filter(DFile_new,is.na(DoS.FY) | is.na(Insured))

#merge DFile_new2 and Master_Joined
DFile_new2 <- merge(DFile_new2,Master_Joined,by=c("Region_SL","Country_SV","Product_BU")) %>%
  mutate(DoS.FY.x = coalesce(DoS.FY.x,DoS.FY.y), Insured.x = coalesce(Insured.x,Insured.y)) %>%
  select(-Insured.y,-DoS.FY.y) %>% rename(Insured=Insured.x, DoS.FY = DoS.FY.x)

#Put all rows in frame
my_out_new <- rbind(DFile_new1,DFile_new2)
```

This yields the same result as OP's code (albeit in a different order):

```
> compare <- function(df1,df2) {
+   idx1 <- c()
+   idx2 <- c()
+   for(i in 1:nrow(df1)) {
+     found <- FALSE
+     for(j in 1:nrow(df2)) {
+       if(!(j %in% idx2)) {
+         idx = as.logical(df1[i,] != df2[j,])
+         d <- suppressWarnings(abs(as.numeric(df1[i,idx])-as.numeric(df2[j,idx]))) < 1e-5
+         if(!(any(is.na(d))) & all(d)) {
+           idx1 <- c(idx1,i)
+           idx2 <- c(idx2,j)
+           break;
+         }
+       }
+     }
+   }
+   rbind(idx1,idx2)
+ }
> compare(my_out,my_out_new)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17]
idx1    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17
idx2    1    2    3   14   15   16   17    4   18     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12
     [,18] [,19] [,20]
idx1    18    19    20
idx2    13    19    20
```

(where my_out is the resulting DFile of the OP's code)